# Sharing with facebook, twitter on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook, share

On the Android os, there is an easy feature for share with facebook, twitter and others.
see this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/shareaction.html).

Is there the same type of thing of iOS?  Or would we need to add specific buttons like "share on Facebook" "share on twitter" for all types of sharing ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is intended as an alternative to finding libraries and blog posts, Paul, since Google provides a lot of content, but no concise answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The built-in functionality you can take advantage of is called the [Social framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Social/Reference/Social_Framework/_index.html).

I did a presentation on this on the NSChat board a couple weeks ago.  [You can find the presentation here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15942/conversation/my-social-framework-presentation) and [my source code here](http://github.com/dautermann/SocialTest).

Comment: Sorry for a 2 year old late reply but I just got to this part in my app development. Do you know if now i still can just use social framework and a little code to create a SHARE button for Facebook? Or now is it a MUST to download FB SDK and make an FB app ID by creating a FB developer profile? 

I'm unsure on this part.

Comment: Have you tried using the Social framework? Here's [an additional tutorial](http://technet.weblineindia.com/mobile/twitter-and-facebook-sharing-in-ios-application-using-social-framework-in-ios-6/) that talks about FB sharing using it, at least for iOS 6.

Answer (score 5):

You may use very easy to use iOS control **[AAShareBubbles](https://github.com/mixdesign/AAShareBubbles)** to present social buttons like:
**Facebook, Twitter, Google+, Tumblr, Vkontakte (vk.com), LinkedIn, Pinterest, Youtube, Vimeo, E-mail**

[image]

Follow the link to github: https://github.com/mixdesign/AAShareBubbles

Answer (score 3):

Try to use ShareKit, it's simple. http://getsharekit.com